# how to setup PostgreSQL username and password on digitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean

Hello I am trying replace my app with the digital Ocean default App but when i try to run,

```
rails db:setup
```

i have this error

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", 
"encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", 
"username"=>"rails", "password"=>nil, 
"database"=>"realestate_development"}
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Here is my database.yml file

```
pool: 5
host: localhost
username: rails
password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
 <<: *default
 database: realestate_development

test:
 <<: *default
 database: realestate_test

production:
 <<: *default
 database: realestate_production
 username: rails
 password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04), it will ask you for password for postgres user or you could create another user, "rails". Then you can update your database.yml with those credentials, especially the password.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear enough: **fe_sendauth: no password supplied**
Accessing to rails console in production and check out ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] value.